# How do I pass in a config.toml when I create a gitlab runner in Kubernetes?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I am able to get into the gitlab runner pod and I do notice that it has a config.toml file in ~/.gitlab-runner. However I want to pass my own config.toml when I create the runner. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a secret:

```
kubectl create secret generic gitlab-runner-config --from-file=./config.toml
```

and configure on your deployment.

```
...
spec:
  ...
  containers:
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: $MOUNT_PATH
      name: runner-conf
  volumes:
  - name: runner-conf
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: gitlab-runner-config
  ...
```